# C# Sending SMTP using System.Threading

Tags: c#, multithreading, smtp

I have developed an application which primarily sends email messages uses SMTP. Sending messages one by one is fine, however I am looking to speed the process. I have created multiple instances of the `SmtpClient` as well as messages to avoid conflict among each other. Because of the separate instances, I assumed performing `.Send()` on multiple threads would work well. However, something with my `Thread` code alone is not working, because I can not send even one email on one thread using this code. I simply receive a vague `"Failure sending mail"` exception. I will post code that works, and the `Thread` that does not work. Could someone share what they believe may be the cause?

**Note** I am not currently looking to use the newer `async` capabilities but instead leveraging `Thread`

**Working Declaration and Method Call:**

```
var SMTP = new SmtpClient
    {
        Host = txtBxSenderHost.Text,
        Port = 587,
        EnableSsl = true,
        DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
        UseDefaultCredentials = false,
        Credentials = new NetworkCredential(strSenderAddress, strSenderPassword)
    };

using (var message = new MailMessage(senderAdrress, toAddress)
    {
        Subject = strSubject,
        Body = strBody
    })

    {
        SMTP.Send(message);
    }
```

**NOT Working Thread declaration and Method Call:**

```
var SMTP = new SmtpClient
    {
        Host = txtBxSenderHost.Text,
        Port = 587,
        EnableSsl = true,
        DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
        UseDefaultCredentials = false,
        Credentials = new NetworkCredential(strSenderAddress, strSenderPassword)
    };

using (var message = new MailMessage(senderAdrress, toAddress)
    {
        Subject = strSubject,
        Body = strBody
    })

    {
        Thread T1 = new Thread(delegate() { SMTP.Send(message); } );
        T1.Start();
    }
```

Comment: Do you have `new Thread` inside a `using` block for `message`? This way, message is likely to be disposed before new thread sends it.

Comment: Wrap your working declaration and working method in another method and then use that method in thread

Comment: I do not. Can you elaborate a bit more please? I'm am also unsure what you mean by being disposed of before the new thread sends it, for testing sake I am only using the one thread. I could also be way off here, I hope you can bare with me.

Comment: Is your thread T1 and delegate declared within the using block? and T1.start() is that also INSIDE the using block. You code is a bit vague about structure of you using statement

Comment: (...and Task Parallel Library makes this kind of threading so much simpler, and more efficient, than managing your own threads)

Comment: I have edited my post to help with any confusion (sorry guys). Is this "Task Parallel" a practical solution for multi-threading smtp?

Comment: Can you show the full exception and any inner exceptions? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpexception.aspx

Comment: @Mojito The `SMTPException` you get back should have a [`StatusCode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpexception.statuscode.aspx) property that will tell you what the actual problem is. I have a suspicion that a single `SMTPClient` can't send more than one email at once though, so you might need to create a new `SMTPClient` for each thread too.

Comment: @Bridge, yes indeed I have created multiple SMTPClients for each thread- the problem however was my coding in declaring and calling the thread itself before I could even get to making multiple ones. Thank you for all the input- I love this site! great community!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Solved:

```
var SMTP = new SmtpClient
        {
            Host = txtBxSenderHost.Text,
            Port = 587,
            EnableSsl = true,
            DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(strSenderAddress, strSenderPassword)
        };

        Thread T1 = new Thread(delegate()
        {
            using (var message = new MailMessage(senderAdrress, toAddress)
            {
                Subject = strSubject,
                Body = strBody
            })
            {
                {
                    SMTP.Send(message);
                }
            }
        });

        T1.Start();
```

Comment: @nsconnector what if exception occurs in new Thread(...), T1.Start() will start or throw an exception?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it even easier by defining everything beforehand and the just calling the new thread.

```
//define everything above

Thread t1 = new Thread(delegate()
{

     SMTP.send(message);

});

t1.Start();
```

Thats what I did and it makes life easier with those curly braces

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use the Smtp.SendAsync method ?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x5x13z6h.aspx

Comment: Because SendAsync still blocks the UI thread and sometimes you don't want the user to have to wait on it. So you send them on a background Thread.

Comment: @BradBamford better solution and code sample without ***SendAsync*** ?

Comment: Using SendAsync for one email is fine, so it doesn't lock up the program... You should NOT use SendAsync to send multiple emails asynchronously!!!! How bloody daft eh! "After calling SendAsync, you must wait for the e-mail transmission to complete before attempting to send another e-mail message using Send or SendAsync."