# C# Dynamic SMTP instances and Threads within Dictionary

Tags: c#, multithreading, dynamic, dictionary, smtp

I have hit another wall. Please review my previous question about multithreading and SMTP [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14518482/c-sharp-sending-smtp-using-system-threading)

Anyways I am trying to dynamically create threads during run time and Call the Start() method, but am receiving a KeyNotFoundException. Any insight to this would be greatly appreciated. If my code is way off here, basically what I am wishing to accomplish is to create a unique SMTP instance running on an individual thread according to user input (count) and run each thread simultaneously.

```
//count is user input (number of messages)  

int instanceCount = 0;

        var vartable = new Dictionary<string, SmtpClient>();
        var vartable2 = new Dictionary<string, Thread>();

        for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        {
            vartable[instanceCount.ToString()] = new SmtpClient
            {
                Host = txtBxSenderHost.Text,
                Port = 587,
                EnableSsl = true,
                DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential(strSenderAddress, strSenderPassword)
            };

            vartable2[instanceCount.ToString()] = new Thread(delegate()
            {
                using (var message = new MailMessage(senderAdrress, toAddress)
                {
                    Subject = strSubject,
                    Body = strBody
                })

                {
                    {
                        ((SmtpClient)vartable[instanceCount.ToString()]).Send(message);
                    }
                }
            });

            instanceCount++;
        }
```

And just for testing sake, I have used "0" to see if working

```
        vartable2["0"].Start();
```

Comment: You need to add a record to the dictionary first, you can't go straight to referencing it with [""]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you store a loop variable inside of a delegate, you need to declare a separate variable outside of the delegate, to avoid receiving the last value of the iteration.

If you make a print statement, you will see the value that each thread is trying to access will be the same, whatever the value of count is. Simply add a variable above the delegate statement:

```
        int tempInstanceCount = instanceCount;
        vartable2[instanceCount.ToString()] = new Thread(delegate()
        {
            using (var message = new MailMessage(senderAdrress, toAddress)
            {
                Subject = strSubject,
                Body = strBody
            })

            {
                {
                    ((SmtpClient)vartable[tempInstanceCount.ToString()]).Send(message);
                }
            }
        });
```